# Controlled TextField loosing focus after every character from keyboard

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Whenever I input a character into the field the focus goes away.
How do I correct that?

```
"use strict"

import React from "react";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardMedia, CardTitle, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';

export var Config = createReactClass({
    setConfig: function() {
        localStorage.serverUrl=this.owner.state.serverUrl;
        location.reload();
       },

    setUrl: function(evt) {
        this.owner.setState({serverUrl: evt.target.value});
        },


    render: function() {
        var {owner}=this.props;
        this.owner=owner;

        return <div>
              <CardTitle title={__("Server")} />
              <CardText>
                  <TextField id="serverUrl" floatingLabelText={__("Server URL")} value={owner.state.serverUrl} onChange={this.setUrl} />
             </CardText>
            <CardActions>
                <RaisedButton label={__("Apply")} onTouchTap={this.setConfig} />
            </CardActions>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

There are of course other elements on the root of the application (the actual logic is a bit more complicated, here only the structure):

```
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
            <div>
            <AppBar title={__("Demo")}
                iconElementRight={right}
                onRightIconButtonClick={this.logon}
                onLeftIconButtonClick={this.toggleMenu} />
            <Drawer open={this.state.menuOpen}
                docked={false}
                onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.toggleMenu}
                onTouchTap={this.toggleMenu}>
                <RaisedButton onTouchTap={this.toggleMenu} label={__("Menu")} />
                <Menu>
                    <MenuEntry owner={this} value="/config" title={__("Server")} />
                    <MenuEntry owner={this} value="/logon" title={__("Logon")} />
                    <Divider />
                    <MenuEntry owner={this} value="/about" title={__("About")} />
                </Menu>
            </Drawer>
            <Paper>
            <Config owner={this} />
            </Paper>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>;
```

Here the implementation MenuEntry

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

export var MenuEntry=createReactClass({

    onChange: function() {
        this.owner.setState({menuOpen: false, systemMenuOpen: false, location: this.value});
        },

    render: function() {
        var {title, owner, value, color}=this.props;
        this.owner=owner;
    this.value=value;

    var selected=(owner.state.location==value);

    return <MenuItem checked={selected} onTouchTap={this.onChange} backgroundcolor={color}>
        {title}
        </MenuItem>;
    }
});
```

Versions:

```
Material-UI: 0.20
React:       16.2.0  
Browser:     Chrome  63.0.3239.123  (Mac & Windows & Android)
             FF 57.0.4  (Mac & Windows)
```

Comment: commenting cause I'm uncertain and without a working example to play with it's hard for me to say. Maybe because you're re rendering onChange? I don't think `autoFocus` is a valid property here. You could add a ref to the textfield as a property `ref="input"` and add a componentDidMount lifecycle and call `this.refs.input.focus()` to get that behavior. You could also try calling `this.refs.input.focus()` in your on change handler.

Comment: Both suggestions (calling focus in componentDidMount or the change handler) do not solve the problem. My App component does tons of other things, so I have to strip that out first...

Comment: hm sorry I can't be of more help. I'm personally not a fan of material-ui so I'm not too familiar with it and without more code it'd be hard for me to debug. Hopefully someone else can shed some light on this for ya

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck - How did you resolve this issue? I just ran into the exact same issue with a Material-UI TextField. (v4.12.2). It was working just fine. The most recent change I made was to implement a full object state variable for the two textboxes on my form.

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in [material-ui docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field) about the `onChange` prop of `<TextField>` :

> Signature: function(event: object, newValue: string) => void
>
> event: Change event targeting the text field.
>
> newValue: The new value of the text field.

So i think you should remove `setUrl` method and change `<TextField>` like this (no need to use `onBlur`) :

```
<TextField id="serverUrl" floatingLabelText={__("Server URL")} value={owner.state.serverUrl} onChange={(evt, value) => this.owner.setState({ serverUrl: value })} />
```

**More comments about the code :**

I'm maybe wrong but calling the `setState` method of a parent component passed in props seems a bad practice to me, you should consider handling the state of the input in the state of `Config` component.

Also, you're using `create-react-class` instead of a class component, it seems useless to use it in your case (you're using es6 import while create-react-class is used to build react app without es6) [see official docs for more infos.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#overview)

**Edit :** I'm able to reproduce a minimal working example :

**Config.js** :

```
import React from 'react';
import createReactClass from 'create-react-class';

import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

export var Config = createReactClass({
  setUrl: function(evt, value) {
    this.owner.setState({ serverUrl: value });
  },

  render: function() {
    var { owner } = this.props;
    this.owner = owner;

    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="serverUrl"
          floatingLabelText={'Server URL'}
          value={owner.state.serverUrl}
          onChange={this.setUrl}
        />
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

**index.js** :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import createReactClass from 'create-react-class';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { Config } from './Config';

var App = createReactClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { serverUrl: 'test' };
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log(this.state.serverUrl);
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Config owner={this} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  },
});

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: It is existing code (that worked with older versions of the components) and I try to change one thing at a time (first keep it working, than make it beautiful).  I can't see a  semantic difference between what I do and what you are doing (you just use a more modern syntax). onBlur was a first shot at the problem (because of some comments I found), but it did not help

Comment: I edited my post with a minimal working example, but your issue seems to come from elsewhere, can you try to identify it by removing some of the other components ?

Comment: I have done the same thing, and it works, so it probably takes another of the components in the full App to reproduce. I am trying to include the other components now 1 by 1,

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with Textfield value props and onBlur. The state value that you are passing to value prop is incorrect i.e., value={owner.state.serverUrl} it should be value={this.owner.state.serverUrl}.

The onBlur fuction doesn't exist in your code but you trying to call onBlur={this.onBlur} which should be removed from TextField component. It seems onBlur is not a valid prop to TextField as per material UI [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field)

```
<TextField id="serverUrl" floatingLabelText={__("Server URL")} value={this.owner.state.serverUrl} onChange={(evt, value) => this.owner.setState({ serverUrl: value })} />
```

Comment: You are right about onBlur. I forgot to remove the attribute when I cleaned the code for the question.  The owner reference in the code is correct, because there is a local variable in the render function with the correct value. But as I told Dyo above, there seems to be another component (not in my code sample now) that is responsible for the issue, that got removed when I cleaned the code for the question, because the problem does not occur in my simplified App (that is currently not in the question)

Comment: hoo yeah! I didn't see owner props in your initial question. Perhaps I didn't notice that part.